# Unable to locate a tab element in Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to locate a tab element in my website. Below is the html code of the tab element:

```
<a class="tab-button has-title has-icon" href="#" role="tab" id="tab-t0-2" aria-controls="tabpanel-t0-2" aria-selected="true">
    <custom-icon class="mmi-tabbar-tpr tab-button-icon"></custom-icon>
    <!---->
    <!----><span class="tab-button-text">TPR</span>
    <!---->
    <div class="button-effect" style="transform: translate3d(-14px, -17px, 0px) scale(1); height: 103px; width: 103px; opacity: 0; transition: transform 313ms, opacity 219ms 94ms;"></div>
</a>
```

Its not in any iframe either. I tried copying its xpath `//*[@id="tab-t0-2"]`, but no luck. Any help will be appreciable.

The error recorded:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='tab-t0-2']"} (Session info:
>   chrome=61.0.3163.100) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940
>   (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: what is the error / exception ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@id='tab-t0-2']"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try following XPath if the id is not dynamic :**

```
//a[@id='tab-t0-2']
```

**If ID is dynamic use :**

```
//a[normalize-space()='TPR']
```

Comment: Tried it, but no luck:  actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='tab-t0-2']")));
  actions.click();
  actions.build().perform();

Comment: Can you please attach full html snippet of your html page ?

Comment: have you tried with second xpath : //a[normalize-space()='TPR']   ?

Comment: Can you provide link of web page or html of your page?

Comment: Hi this got resolved.. issue was that my action got performed before the page load..i gave an implicit wait and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath

By by = By.xpath(**"//span[.='TPR']"**) or

By.cssSelector(**"div[class='button-effect']"**))

let me know if it works.

Comment: Or 
You can use a katalon  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid plugin for chrome browser.
and record your test with it bu clicking the tab
it gives you all possible elements for that.
then you can try one by one in your code.